# Setting up a redirect on route 53 including path redirection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

We have a website running on AWS ECS Fargate via an application load balancer.

Due to a rebrand the url is due to change however we would want all old links to still work.

We have an old url called **oldurl.com** and a new one **newurl.com**

We want a setup whereby if a user clicks on **oldurl.com/this/path** it will automatically redirect to **newurl.com/this/path**

How do I go about this?

Comment: Route53 is the wrong tool here since you apparently want an HTTP direct and not a DNS "forwarding". Use the ALB you already have instead: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-to-another-domain-with-alb/

Comment: OK. So what is your question or issue?

Answer (score 0):

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-to-another-domain-with-alb/

This guide here solved the problem.